# jquery index() method problem selecting by attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

Could someone please take a [look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/ybKzJ/)?

You'll see the first alert prints -1 whereas I was expecting 1. Anyone know why?

Basic code from the fiddle:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="0" />0
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />3
alert($(':checkbox').index("input[value='1']"));
alert($(':checkbox').index("input[value='0']"));
```

Comment: side note, only [value=0] is returning the proper index. subsequent values are all -1.

Comment: yes, selecting by other attributes seems to work --- it is something about the value attribute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the selectors reversed:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RaV35/

```
 // element---v    collection----------v
alert($("input[value='0']").index(":checkbox"));
alert($("input[value='1']").index(":checkbox"));
```

When passing the [`index()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method a selector, the individual element for which you want the index is the element against which `.index()` is invoked.

The selector you pass to `.index()` represents the collection against which the element in the original jQuery object is tested.

When the original jQuery object (on the left) also contains a collection, only the first one is tested for its index against the selector on the right. That's why the one with `value="0"` was working.

```
 //   v--- only the first is tested (and it has value="0")...
$(':checkbox').index("input[value='0']")
 //   ----------------------^ ...and it is at index 0 of this "collection"
```

Comment: This is correct and on a slightly closer reading of the docs, is the correct behavior.  But talk about principle of least surprise.  This is the reverse of the way most people would expect it to work.

Comment: @numbers1311407: I completely agree. They already had `$('selector').index(element)`, but I guess they felt the need to give a shortcut to what would otherwise simply be `$('selector').index($('selector'));`. Should have just left it alone in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks Patrick -- I think the API is confusing (sort of reversed in this case) but I see you have the correct reading.

Comment: Good call anyway.  I'd never used this method before and briefly hit the docs for the gist.  Didn't pick up on the reversal at all.  Ty for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($(':checkbox[value='1']').index());
alert($(':checkbox[value='0']').index());
```

Comment: alert($(':checkbox[value='0']').index()); <------- this is not valid. can you link to a working fiddle? EDIT: i see your quotes are just wrong. In any case, do you know why mine didn't work?

Comment: The original didnt work because index() wasnt being passes a jQuery object or DOM element it was being passed a string.

Comment: from the docs: "If we use a string as the .index() method's argument, it is interpreted as a jQuery selector string. The first element among the object's matched elements which also matches this selector is located."  Also, it does seem to work for "[value=0]".

Comment: @Matt -- It says clearly that it interprets a string as a selector

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it a jQuery object: http://jsfiddle.net/ybKzJ/1/

```
alert($(':checkbox').index($("input[value='1']")));
alert($(':checkbox').index("input[value='0']"));
```

Edit:

No that doesn't seem right as the second one is working just fine.

...curious...

Comment: If you rearrange the `<input>`'s, it seems only the first one is recognized.  A moment ago I did something where I rearranged them and it worked for both elements, but after refreshing the page it stopped.  No changes to the HTML other than copying and pasting to change the order.

Comment: @numbers1311407: I think it's time to open a bug tracker

Comment: I just implemented a test outside of jsfiddle and got the same result.  It does appear to be a bug.  What's odd is when toying with the jsfiddle script, after a little copying and pasting, it suddenly worked for me.  I changed nothing of consequence though, and could not reproduce the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you have to use `index()` at all.  Why not just put it all in the selector:

```
$('input:checkbox[value="2"]');
```

You can see it work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Xa6hA/

If you did want to do it in multiple stages, it would be more logical to me to do it like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').filter('[value="3"]');
```

This gets all the checkboxes, then filters that list down to just the ones with `value="3"` which seems a lot more intuitive than the way `index()` appears to work.

Comment: You use `.index()` when you want the index *number* of the element as opposed to the element itself.